What is the gradient of $Ax$?
I am trying to figure out if the gradient of $Ax$ is either $A$ or $A^T$. I am finding conflicting sources online.
Assuming $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $f(x) = Ax$, where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, we could rewrite $f(x)$ as
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &=  Ax  \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \dots  & a_{2n} \\
\ddots  \\
a_{m1}  & a_{m2}  & \dots  & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_{1} + a_{12}x_{2} + \dots + a_{1n}x_{n} \\
a_{21}x_{1} + a_{22}x_{2} + \dots + a_{2n}x_{n} \\
\ddots \\
a_{m1}x_{1} + a_{m2}x_{2} + \dots + a_{mn}x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Now am I correct in assuming that the gradient of $f$ would be the Jacobian matrix?
If we take each element of this resulting column vector to be a function $f_{1}, \dots, f_{m}$, then, according to the Wikipedia definition of the Jacobian, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla^Tf_{1} \\
\nabla^Tf_{2} \\
\vdots \\
\nabla^Tf_{m}
\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}  & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}  & \dots  & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}} \\
\ddots \\
\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}}   & \frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{2}}  & \dots  & \frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & \dots  & a_{1n} \\
a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\ddots \\
a_{m1}  & a_{m2}  & \dots & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}  \\
&= A
\end{align}
$$
I am wondering if the proof above is correct, and if the gradient of $Ax$ is indeed A?
My confusion regarding this mainly comes from my lecture notes and slides stating that this derivative should in fact be $A^T$. This would we be the case if we considered the Jacobian to be transpose of the form above, but I do not see why we would do that. Wikipedia does state: "Some authors define the Jacobian as the transpose of the form given above". This is very confusing to me, what is the ground truth in this situation then?

I think it has to do with you using the transpose jacobian and the lectures using the jacobian or viceversa.

Think of $\nabla$ and $f$ as two (column) vectors; the outer product of two vectors generates a matrix and this is written as $\nabla f^T$. So element $i,j$ of this matrix is $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ and using your definition of $f_j$ we get $a_{ji}$. This means that $\nabla f^T=A^T$. What you have written is not $\nabla f^T$; it is $(\nabla f^T)^T$ and $(A^T)^T=A$ as you have shown.

Some authors do define the Jacobian differently, so you need to be aware of that possibility.  It's normally clear from context, or perhaps by looking for a definition elsewhere in the text, exactly what the author means by gradient and Jacobian and derivative of a function of a vector.
Most often, if $f(x)$ is a scalar valued function of a vector, then the first order Taylor series approximation is
$f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + \nabla f(x)^{T}\Delta x$.
Here the gradient is a column vector of the partial derivatives of $f(x)$ with respect to $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$.
Most often, the Jacobian of a (possibly vector valued) function of a vector $x$, $F(x)$, is defined so that
$F(x+\Delta x) \approx F(x)+J(x)\Delta x$.
Here, the $i$th row of $J(x)$ contains the partial derivatives of $F_{i}(x)$ with respect to $x_{j}$ for $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$.   In other words, the rows of the $J$ matrix are the transposed gradients of the $F_{i}(x)$ functions.
If you're using these conventions, then the Jacobian is the transpose of the gradient.
For $F(x)=Ax$, using the defintition above, the Jacobian of $F(x)$ is $J(x)=A$.
